# Can't get IP address from range expander on SOME devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, touchpad

I installed a Linksys WRE54G range expander.  It's working fine with my Windows 7 laptop, but not so much with my Palm Pre and my Ubuntu netbook.  Both of those devices act the same... they see the wireless network, say they're "connecting" for a long time, then finally fail saying they can't get an IP address.

Unfortunately, I think this leaves me in "finger pointing hell" where I won't be able to get support from any vendor, because they will each point to the other as the culprit.

Comment: Maybe the repeater is too far from the main router, so lower power devices can't detect the signal? Can they connect to the main router's wireless?
(Do you like the Palm Pre BTW?)

Comment: No, even if I put the netbook in the same places I always used it before I installed the repeater, I still get that... the Palm Pre is great for the most part... except for a few points that I think will be eventually improved

Comment: I have copied this to http://serverfault.com/questions/104969/cant-get-ip-address-from-range-expander-on-some-devices